# Tikz coordinates relative to one node

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility, coordinates, calc, relative

Using both `calc` and `|-` would be a convenient way to refer to "inner, relative coordinates" of a node, with

- `(0, 0)` meaning `node.center`,
- `(0, 1)` meaning `node.east` and
- `(.3, -.5)` meaning somewhere precise (but relative) in the south east quarter.

However, as described [here](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1cs3) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447936/72679), the following coordinate is not parsed:

```
($(node.center)!.3!(node.east)$ |- $(node.center)!-.5!(node.north)$)
```

So the following convenience macro does not work:

```
\newcommand{\relativeToNode}[3]{($(#1.center)!#2!(#1.east)$ |- $(#1.center)!#3!(#1.north)$)}
```

How nice would it be to write:

```
\node (inner) at (\relativeToNode{outer}{.3}{-.5}) {hey!};
```

Is there any chance to get this working?
Any workaround that would not involve defining intermediate macros or coordinates (whose names would have to be picked *etc.*)?

Comment: `tikz` doesn't enable calculation of coordinates on the way as you desired. you should defined one auxiliary coordinate: `\coordinate (aux) at ($(node1.south) + (1,0)$);
\draw ($(node1.south) + (1,0)$) to (aux |- node2.north);`

Comment: @Zarko Well, it seems that it is finally possible like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447937/72679) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your use case you don't even need the `calc` library. You can define style `relative to node=<node name>` that shifts and scales the coordinate system accordingly:

```
\tikzset{
    relative to node/.style={
        shift={(#1.center)},
        x={(#1.east)},
        y={(#1.north)},
    }
}
```

Then you can place your node with

```
\path[relative to node=outer] (-0.4,-0.5) node {Hello};
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    relative to node/.style={
        shift={(#1.center)},
        x={(#1.east)},
        y={(#1.north)},
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=3cm,draw=red] (outer) at (3,3) {};

        % Only for the grid
        \begin{scope}[relative to node=outer]
            \foreach \ratio in {-1,-0.8,...,1}{
                \draw[help lines] (-1,\ratio) -- (1,\ratio);
                \draw[help lines] (\ratio,-1) -- (\ratio,1);
            }
            \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
            \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \end{scope}

        \path[relative to node=outer] (-0.4,-0.5) node {Hello};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) Since this is not my core problem, but the core problem has no solution according to Zarko, I'll edit the OP so it matches your answer best.