# Combining calc and perpendicular coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility, coordinates, calc

As it is described [there](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1cs3), the following does not compile:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,  0) (node1) {Hello};
\node at (0, -2) (node2) {World};

% working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( node1.south |- node2.north);

% not working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) |- node2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why? How to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax of the `line to` operation given in the manual is to place `|-` between two coordinates:

> Sometimes you want to connect two points via straight lines that are only horizontal and vertical. For this, you can use two path  construction operations.
>
> \path . . . -|< coordinate or cycle> . . . ;
>
> This operation means
>   “first horizontal, then vertical.”

Following by these example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node(a) [draw] {A} (1,1) node(b) [draw] {B};
\draw (a.north) |- (b.west);
\draw[color=red] (a.east) -| (2,1.5) -| (b.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and these drawing:
[image: two-path]

Thus, this two-path operation is not intended to make a translation from one point to another. 
This is a handy shortcut when you need to draw horizontal lines followed by vertical lines or vice versa.

You just have to write (syntactically) in your code:

```
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) |- (node2.north);
```

instead of

```
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( ( ( $ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) |- node2.north);`
```

Your code becomes like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,  0) (node1) {Hello};
\node at (0, -2) (node2) {World};

% working:
%\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( node1.south |- node2.north);

% now working too:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to  ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) |- (node2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To have the same path as the one you want, you must build your path as indicated by @marmot or @ignasi.

Comment: Not clear what is the use of `($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to  ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $)` in the second path.

Comment: @Kpym yes, i edited my answer

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness: a version that is really the equivalent of the first. AndreC's nice answer is correct but I don't see how the second path, which has a corner, is the shifted version of the first one.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,  0) (node1) {Hello};
\node at (0, -2) (node2) {World};

% working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( node1.south |- node2.north);

% not working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ([xshift=1cm] node1.south |- node2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, this adds semantics to the syntactic correction, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can always declare an auxiliary coordinate and use it. This way you don't need to  remember which is the working syntax ;-)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,  0) (node1) {Hello};
\node at (0, -2) (node2) {World};

% working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( node1.south |- node2.north);

% working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) coordinate (aux) to (aux |- node2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is true. I was rather willing to avoid this (the lazyness is about 'picking an unused name for the auxiliary coordinate' XD), but it is a useful workaround. Cheers :)

Comment: @iago-lito you just need to declare a non used name if all previously declared are relevant later on, otherwise you can reuse them.

Comment: Yes, this is how I also do it in the general case.... ;-) +1

Comment: Correct. This is an easy choice when working on a neat document. Not when rushing to produce a big dirty one. I hate this but sometimes your environment dictates it's better you don't ponder anything :'( I usually enforce `aux`, `tp`, *etc.* never to be "relevant later on".. until one day I'll wonder "what's happening?!" XD