# Update figure labels in a PDF

Tags: graphics, labels

I have some pdf figures that I generated in Mathematica with latex labels using matex. I need to update the labels on the figures, but I generated them a few years ago and I can't get the Mathematica code to run again now. Would there be some reasonably straightforward way in latex to put new figure labels on top of the old ones? I would prefer a method which would modify the pdfs of the figures themselves. I am importing them into a latex document, so I could add commands into my document to do this if necessary.

Here is one of my figures as an example
[image]

Comment: (i) convert `pdf` image to `epd`, (ii) use `psfrag` package and replace desired labels. (I never used).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'labels'? Do you mean tick labels on the x-axis and y-axis of a line chart or something? Or edge labels on a network graph? Or some kind of caption or figure title at the top or bottom?

Comment: @Marijn edge labels on a network graph, I've added an example to my question

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451833/ would work, when you draw a white filled rectangle with the new label in it over the current label.

Comment: @Marijn, oh yeah this is the kind of thing I had in mind. I can't work out, are they putting white rectangles down in the example code that you linked? Or is that your additional idea? Can I get some kind of text command in Tikz that has a solid white background do you think?

Comment: [fill=white] will hide the background.  Don't remember if it also hides the new text.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, do you mean `[fill=white]` in  `\node at (x,y) {text}`?

Comment: @joe - Das ist eine grosse Zehn Vier gutter Kamerad!  (yes) *from Black Forrest Bluegrass by PDQ Bach

Comment: @JohnKormylo, glad you included the '(yes)', the rest was totally lost on me haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tikz as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451833/) linked to me by Marijn in the comments, and using `[fill=white]` as suggested by John Kormylo, I solved the problem like this;

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{giffrommyquestion}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
 \node [fill=white,scale = .9] at (.48,.32) {$|0]\langle0|$};
 \node [fill=white,scale = .9] at (.48,.15) {$\alpha|4]\langle1|$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```